# rewrite path with /img/ to index with ?parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I really can't wrap my head around htaccess and rewrite rules, so I'm gonna ask this question straight out:

How can I rewrite this:

```
folder/subfolder/img/filename/
```

... to this:

```
?file=folder/subfolder/filename.jpg
```

Folder depth (subfolder) is optional. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (^|.+?/)img/([^/]+)/?$ ?file=$1$2.jpg [L,QSA,NC]
```